# How to simplify my javascript code, it seems too long and messy?

Tags: javascript, html

This code basically makes 7 a tags on my page, onclick, change the content of another div tag. The code works but it's too long. I am thinking maybe something to do with else if statements, but I am new to javascript and I don't think I am there yet.

```
<script>
            function showBaseChakra(text) {
                if(text.id == "baseChakra") {
                    document.getElementById("baseChakraInfo").style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("defaultText").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("sacralChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("solarPlexusChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("heartChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("throatChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("browChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("crownChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                }
            }

            function showSacralChakra(text) {
                if(text.id == "sacralChakra") {
                    document.getElementById("sacralChakraInfo").style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("defaultText").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("baseChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("solarPlexusChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("heartChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("throatChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("browChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("crownChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                }
            }

            function showSolarPlexusChakra(text) {
                if(text.id == "solarPlexusChakra") {
                    document.getElementById("solarPlexusChakraInfo").style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("defaultText").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("baseChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("sacralChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("heartChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("throatChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("browChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("crownChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                }
            }

            function showHeartChakra(text) {
                if(text.id == "heartChakra") {
                    document.getElementById("heartChakraInfo").style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("defaultText").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("baseChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("sacralChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("solarPlexusChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("throatChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("browChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("crownChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                }
            }

            function showThroatChakra(text) {
                if(text.id == "throatChakra") {
                    document.getElementById("throatChakraInfo").style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("defaultText").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("baseChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("sacralChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("solarPlexusChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("heartChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("browChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("crownChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                }
            }

            function showBrowChakra(text) {
                if(text.id == "browChakra") {
                    document.getElementById("browChakraInfo").style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("defaultText").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("baseChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("sacralChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("solarPlexusChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("heartChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("throatChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("crownChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                }
            }

            function showCrownChakra(text) {
                if(text.id == "crownChakra") {
                    document.getElementById("crownChakraInfo").style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("defaultText").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("baseChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("sacralChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("solarPlexusChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("heartChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("throatChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("browChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Give same class to the elements.Using class you can select all elements and hide at once.Then make the required element visible.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a single function like this - Give all the elements a shared class - let's say chakras - and loop them:

```js
function change(text) {
   [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('chakras'), function(val) {
        val.style.display = val.id == text.id + 'Info' ? 'block' : 'none';
   });
}

change({id: 'baseChakra'}); // just to demo, call the function like before
```

```html
<div class="chakras" id="baseChakraInfo">a</div>
<div class="chakras" id="defaultText">b</div>
<div class="chakras" id="sacralChakraInfo">c</div>
<div class="chakras" id="solarPlexusChakraInfo">d</div>
<div class="chakras" id="heartChakraInfo">e</div>
<div class="chakras" id="throatChakraInfo">f</div>
<div class="chakras" id="browChakraInfo">g</div>
<div class="chakras" id="crownChakraInfo">h</div>
```

Comment: Why not just `[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('chakras'), function...)`?

Comment: I got used to [].slice.call() because according to jsperf it is faster (https://jsperf.com/oneanother), but so many people ask me that, that I changed it now :)  @Derek朕會功夫

Comment: Quite interesting that it is slightly faster to first convert it into an array.

Comment: I've been wondering, too... @Derek朕會功夫 -- well not sure how reliable jsperf is...

Answer (score -1):

```
function show(list, show) {
    for(var key in list){
        document.getElementById(key).style.display= "none";
    }
    document.getElementById(show).style.display= "block";
}
```

you may try a function like this above